# Plot in nowhere

Tags: r, plot

I am using the function `plotMDS()` of package `limma` that makes a plot by the simple `plot()` format of R, and also returns the position of the points on the plot as output. I want to use the output of `plotMDS()` to produce my own beautiful plot.

Is there any way to run `plotMDS()` without having it's plot really generated? The reason I ask so is that I have already casted the output to a PDF file and I don't want the original plot of the `plotMDS()` to be there!

Comment: maybe open another device and use `dev.next`/`dev.set` etc. to switch over to the other device and back again.

Comment: As it stands this question is very vague.  How about a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - What package?

Comment: How can anyone answer without knowing what the function/package is?

Comment: Why not just capture the output  of the plot outside the pdf call and then create whatever graphics you want for the pdf?

Comment: @mnel Because there is a sequence of many plots to be created, I have already opened pdf file long time ago.

Comment: @joran I believe providing the name of function/package is not necessary here, as my question is general and other people running other functions of other packages may have some similar question some day

Comment: Make your example reproducible (including your workflow) and perhaps you will get a useful answer.

Comment: Functions within packages can do many weird and wonderful things  in nonstandard ways. @joran is spot on, your answer (and any similar problem) will be *entirely* dependent on the internal workings of the function.

Comment: @BenBolker Great! the problem was solved by dev.new() and dev.off() before and after. Why don't you make your comment as answer to be accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @BenBolker, it can be done like this:

```
pdf("Some file")
...
dev.new() # Putting new plots to nowhere
mds <- plotMDS(data)
dev.off() # Restoring new plots to the PDF file
plot(...) # Making the desired plot using mds
...
dev.off() # Closing PDF file
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your answer it seems like this might be a reasonable alternative:

```
mds <- plotMDS(data)
pdf("Some file")
...
plot(...) # Making the desired plot using mds
...
dev.off() # Closing PDF file
```

I don't know exactly what you're doing but if you're interested in reproducible documents then you could also use the `knitr` package to create your output.  It would be *very* easy to suppress a single plot and then plot later using knitr.

Comment: Thanks, but as I informed in the comments there is a sequence of many commends to be run, and many charts to be created. So I have to make the PDF first (for the earlier charts) and compute the plotMDS later